# Is it possible to control the volume on the mame Simulator?

Tags: mame

I am currently enjoying metal slug on my pc thanks to the MAME32 simulator, but I also want to play my music on the same pc simultaneously, but I can't seem to find where in the settings I can control the volume for games. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Way back then on Mame32 0.106:

- Options menu
- Default Game Options
- Sound tab
- Volume Attenuation slider, pull towards the left to reduce volume.

This would apply to all games.

Within games, volume down/up should be keys "-" and "=" by default, but it's not working for me. I'll update if I find out why.

Comment: Thanks, big time, it didn't work at first until I rebooted my system, worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I use the tilde (²) key, European keyboard, ingame. Arrows left or right then decrease or increase volume.

Comment: "European keyboard" is a bit vague: do you mean ISO? Is it QWERTY?